# How to convert a bootstrap navbar into wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert a bootstrap website to wordpress and my current problem is with the navbar. I created all my files for the wordpress, created the menu and can actually see. The problem is that in small screens, the menu is not collapsing.
Below is my code for the header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
 <title><?php bloginfo('name') ?></title>
  <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>    
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
      ?>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Followed by the index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The functions.php:

```
<?php 
  require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
  register_nav_menus( array(
 'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'Experiment Website' ),
  ) );
?>
```

And finally the footer:

```
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

How can I make the menu collapse in small screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already wrapped your navwalker with a `navbar-collapse collapse` div so remove this line from your navwalker code --> **`container_class   => collapse navbar-collapse,`**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. it worked perfectly and definitely I just learned more.

Comment: Glad I could help Elton. Do mark this as the right answer if it fixes the issue. Cheers man